# Alternatives to "vice versa"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I've run into a road block at the end of my essay about stereotyping, where I write "...no matter how I feel labeling that individual—or vice versa." My essay featured scenarios in which both I stereotyped an individual and the same individual stereotyped me (in short). However, I realized that this quote doesn't have the same intended effect, since the placement of "vice versa" is more than a little confusing.

What I'm wondering is whether there is a more efficient, cleaner way of saying "...no matter how I feel labeling that individual or how I feel about him labeling me."

This could be applied to other scenarios in speech, when simply dropping "and vice versa" after a statement may seem natural but is actually very difficult to comprehend.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Thesuarus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/vice%20versa?s=t) gives a list of twenty or so alternatives for *vice versa*, if that helps.

Comment: I always say "versa vice".

Comment: Please do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). They are out of scope and your question may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”; “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”; *[Writers Stack Exchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)*.

Answer (score 0):

If the essay is written to express your perspective, you could rephrase the sentence to favor you as the primary subject with an interrupting clarification that the statement also applies to the other individual. Explicitly: "...no matter how I--or the other individual--feel about the act of labeling."

Comment: That's a good idea, but I usually don't like turning verbs into objects (i.e. act of labeling). I would prefer something more direct/straightforward. I'll still take this into consideration, though.